# Closure, and sets defined by intersections of sets

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have a question about the "logical consistency" of the common intersection constructions.  It's a minor thing but has always bothered me a bit.  I've seen these in many guises, such as "a closure of A is the intersection of all closed sets containing A"; the smallest subspace/measure generated by a set etc.

So let's stick with the simple topological example: Let $\mathcal{F} = \{F | A \subset F, F\space closed \}$.  Since we go on to show that $A \subset \bar{A}$ and that the closure is closed, isn't, by definition, $\bar{A} \in \mathcal{F}$?
In that case, the equality $\bar{A} = \bigcap_{F \in \mathcal{F}} F$ is certainly true by the properties of $\bigcap$ and $\subset$.  However, I feel that is not what is intended, which is why I see the definitions as either a bit circular, tautological or "under specified".
Could someone provide a bit of clarity, or explain where my reasoning is breaking down?
Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, $\operatorname{cl}A\in\mathcal{F}$, though we don’t know that until we prove that an arbitrary intersection of closed sets is closed. What we’re saying is simply that the partial order $\langle\mathcal{F},\subseteq\rangle$ has a minimum element, and we define that element to be the closure of $A$. I really don’t see why this should seem at all problematic.

Comment: By way of analogy: we define $\lfloor x\rfloor$ to be the maximum of all integers not exceeding $x$. Let $\mathcal F = \{ f\colon f\le x\}$. The equality $\lfloor x\rfloor =\max\mathcal F$ is true by the properties of $\max$ and $\le$. Of course $\lfloor x\rfloor \in \mathcal F$, but that doesn't seem circular or troublesome to me.

Comment: What is your actual question? When you ask us to find where your reasoning breaks down it sounds like you believe you've proved something false. But every _mathematical_ statement you make is true! What's the problem you see here, and why is it a problem? Really. You say 'I feel that is not what is intended, which is why I see the definitions as either a bit circular, tautological or "under specified"' without any indication of what the difficulty is.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I like that way of thinking about it.  I realize the definition is a direct result of what you say, but somehow it feels more "natural" to me.  Thank you.

Comment: @tpso: You’re welcome.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The question is perhaps a little "meta".  Best was I can try and describe it is that I was staring at definition and it was giving me a "Russel's Paradox" vibe, in that we are defining something to be an operation on a set of sets, but the thing we're defining is already in the set, and hence the intersection equality is obviously true, which is what I meant by circular/tautology.  I started to wonder if there was some unwritten assumption I had always missed/misunderstood and hence asked here.

Comment: it appears that the question is why you got that vibe. Thats not a mathematical question - sorry, but among all the mathematical things you said I can't see where the problem might be. This is true, that's true, fine, now what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a set $A$ our objective is to find the "smallest" closed set $\overline{A}$ containing $A$. In order to do so we need to know what it means to be the smallest, if $X$ and $Y$ are sets such that $X \subset Y$ or $Y \subset X$, then we can certainly tell which one is smaller or equal to the other, but in general, the sets in the partial ordered  family $\mathcal{F}$ are not one contained in the other, so it doesn't seem clear which element to pick as the smallest. Thankfully, we know that this family is closed under arbitrary intersection, therefore intersecting all the elements of this family gives another element in it such that it is contained in all the others, this element is $\textbf{the}$ minimal element of the family and this property is the reason of why we can define the smallest closed set containing $A$. The crucial part of this construction was that the family was closed under arbitrary intersection and the same argument can be used to subgroups, subspaces, $\sigma$-algebras, etc.